# Unable to import a class in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is probably a beginner question but I'm really pulling my hair out.

I have a very simple Python script "foo":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.do_something()

  def do_something(self):
    print "foo"

def main():
  Foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Script works fine:

```
$ python foo.py 
foo
```

I want to test the function "do_something" in unittest and I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import foo
from foo import *

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_foo(self):
    Foo()

def main():
  unittest.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

If I run the tests, however, I get:

```
$ python pyunit/foo.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_foo (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyunit/foo.py", line 9, in test_foo
    Foo()
NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

My project structure:

```
$ tree 
.
├── foo.py
└── pyunit
    └── foo.py
```

I have been playing around with `inspect`, `dir()`, the Python debugger etc but I'm getting nowhere.

Although `import foo` and `from foo import *` both execute fine, and I see the function `main` imported from that file, the class itself `Foo` doesn't seem to be imported.

My objective, ultimately, is to then write unit tests for the functions in the class `Foo`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using one import statement? `from foo import *`, then you don't need the `import foo` statement above

Comment: Could it be that the `foo` module you import is the test file instead of the original? Try renaming your `pyunit/foo.py` into `pyunit/test_foo.py` and see what happens.

Comment: No, I tried both of these suggestions and I have the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same file name (foo.py) in your module. Change your test module to test_foo instead. *Explicit is better than implicit.*

When importing a module from a parent directory, you need to use `from <parent_dir> import <module_name>`, so in your case you should state `from <parent_dir> import foo`

You encounter the `ImportError: No module named foo` error becuase your module is not part of your `sys.path`.

Simplest way to import your local directory to python's lookup path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Before the other import statements. This will append the project dir to the path. If you have multiple classes with the same name, you better use `sys.path.insert(0, '.')` to push the path into the first position

Comment: No, I'm afraid that doesn't work. That leads to an error `ImportError: No module named pyunit`.

Comment: Add to your pyunit folder a new empty file named `__init__.py`, this will make python address the folder as a package

Comment: Nope. no difference.

Comment: Can you update the folder tree after changing the file names?

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with this info since seems there's no way to paste it here.

Comment: Ok so you are running `python pyunit/test_foo.py` now instead of `foo.py` right? then your import needs to be changed to: `import <top_level_dir> import foo` where top level dir is where `foo.py` resides

Comment: Ok I was able to get the file using:
`import sys ; sys.path.insert(0, '.') ; from foo import *`. You're on the right track. Your answer, as it stands, is not correct. Importing from `pyunit` doesn't make much sense to me, and it certainly doesn't work. Would you like to fix it?

Comment: @AlexHarvey you had multiple issues in one question ;) I updated my answer accordignly

Comment: I believe I only had one issue, which was that as Francis Colas suggested, I was accidentally importing from the foo.py file inside my tests directory (i.e. inside my pyunit directory). By trying to turn the pyunit directory into a module, which is what you seem to be suggesting, I would still be importing from the wrong place, and in any case, as I said, the code you provided simply doesn't work. So I can't mark the answer as correct unless you fix that.

Comment: @AlexHarvey done, I removed what's not relevant and summarized it

Answer (score 1):

Python tests can be disturbing especially with relative imports.
So I got a work around.

First and Foremost: I suggest you install **pytest** which resolves the name in the sys.path that the test module is contained.. Install it by running `pip install pytest`.

For the relative import, you are trying to access the module outside the test package, to resolve this use the **dot** representation of imports, that is

```
from ..foo import Foo
```

Make sure you have removed `import foo`

Then try running the test `pytest` or `pytest test_foo.py`(if you are inside the pyunit folder)